# RCA 2in1 to Monitor

Tags: windows-10, vga, rca

I have an RCA 2in1. I want to hook it up to one of the monitors on my dual monitor. I have a converter that I plugged into the usb port on the RCA and it has VGA on the other side. I plugged everything in right and I have literally nothing on my screen. What's your advice? Do I need to change something on my RCA?

Comment: A lot of those USB-to-VGA adapters are capable of only up to 720p. Is your resolution set too high?

Comment: I set it to 800 x 600

Comment: It did not do anything different. My monitor says "Entering power saving mode"

Comment: You sure the right source (VGA) is selected on your monitor? Also try unplugging the power on your monitor and plug it back in; not just a simple off and on of the power button.

Comment: might be super handy to add a link to the specific device (tablet? a 2 in 1 to me is a radio/tape player)

Comment: I will add it. One second.https://www.walmart.com/ip/RCA-11-Galileo-Pro-with-WiFi-11.5-Touchscreen-Tablet-PC-with-Keyboard-Case-Featuring-Android-6.0-Marshmallow-Operating-System/53990867?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227049506748&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=147093308622&wl4=aud-261800281660:pla-257855084862&wl5=9008680&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=53990867&wl13=&veh=sem

Comment: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-to-vga-adapter-black/4974300.p?skuId=4974300

Comment: It has Windows 10 on it. A desk top version.

Comment: Hold on that RCA isn't like mine. ops.

Comment: Oh, that link you provided shows an Android tablet.

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/ip/44656210?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227032862786&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=66579676232&wl4=aud-261800281660:pla-130448067632&wl5=9008680&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=44656210&wl13=&veh=sem

Comment: There is the new link :) Sorry about that!

Comment: Did you install the drivers for that adapter?

Comment: No... What should I install?

Comment: [https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PU96203/4974300](https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PU96203/4974300) - Support & Downloads tab at the bottom.